# Creating a matrix of objects in python

Tags: python, oop, object, matrix

I need to make a matrix of objects in python. I have found other solutions in various languages however cannot find a reliable and efficient method to do this in python.

Given the class

```
class Cell():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = none 
        self.attribute1 = False
        self.attribute2 = False
```

I want to make a matrix of multiple 'cells' as efficiently as possible. Since the size of the matrix will be larger than 20 by 20, an iterative method would be useful. Any contributions are helpful

Comment: A matrix like a x*y array?

Comment: You should look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

Comment: @Guimoute Yes. Like a two dimensional array

Comment: @Mariusz FYI the `np.matrix` class is no longer recommended in Numpy v1.15: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Update for correctness

The `numpy.full` answer will copy the single existing `Cell()`, giving your references to one object. Use a list comprehension here:

```py
row = [[Cell() for _ in range(num_cols)] for _ in range(num_rows)]
```

### Old answer

If you already have defined your objects, list comprehensions can help here:

```
num_rows = 5
num_cols = 6

row = [Cell() for i in range(num_cols)]
# The original way doesn't behave exactly right, this avoids 
# deep nesting of the array. Also adding list(row) to create
# a new object rather than carrying references to row to all rows
mat = [list(row) for i in range(num_rows)]

#[[Cell(), Cell(), Cell()...], [...], ..., [Cell(), ..., Cell()]]
```

You can wrap them in `numpy.array` if you want to as well

## NumPy array full

You could also use the numPy `full` method which is built-in and generates an `n` by `m` numpy array filled with your values:

```
mat = numpy.full((num_rows, num_cols), Cell())
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.full.html#numpy.full)

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @OscarWilson Just so you know . in this matrix the entire rows are the same which means modifiing one row affects all the rows so if you are dont want something like that either put `list(row)` or something because what is happening here is called shallow copy

Comment: I'm a little confused by this answer. Don't you want a row to have 6 cells (i.e. the number of columns)? So shouldn't it be this?
`row = [Cell() for i in range(num_cols)]`
`mat = [list(row) for i in range(num_rows)]`

Comment: @AlbinPaul It may have been many many years ago but I wish high school me had read this comment. I spent a very long time trying to figure out why all my Cells were changing together (I was new to programming and didn't understand object references). Makes me laugh reading it now and remembering this old project

Comment: @OscarWilson I do laugh at my old code as well. :)

Comment: @AlbinPaul ah carrying around a reference to the same cell. Old code does bite sometimes, doesn't it? I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just using nested lists?

Something like:

```
mtx = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
mtx[1][1] # 4
```

Edit:
You can add elements to a list using the append method.

```
the_list = []
for item in iterator_or_something:
    the_list.append(Cell(item.a, item,b))
```

If it is a fixed size and you know it:

```
the_list = []
for x in range(0, 500):
    the_list.append(Cell())
```

Comment: I understand how to use nested lists however the main problem is creating a list of objects.

Comment: What do you mean with a list of objects? `object_list = [Cell(), Cell(), Cell()]`

Comment: Yes just like that however the size of the matrix may be a bit larger than three elements. An iterative method would be useful. I will update the question to clarify this

Comment: Using append could be an option?

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance what size your matrix is you could initialize a numpy array using `np.empty` or `np.zeros` and then fill in the cells using indexing.

Or you could append items to lists and then convert to an array by `np.array(list)`.
You'll want your matrix as a numpy array for any calculations you do.

Answer (score 0):

```
Size = 20
Matrix = np.zeros((Size, Size))

for x in range(0, Size):
    for y in range(0, Size):
        Matrix[x][y] = Cell()
```